# New Intent triggered but not working

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

I have created a AWS LEX BOT. I have used 2 intents. In 1st Intent i have used lambda function which triggered the 2nd Intent. This triggering works but i am getting error from 2nd Intent. Here is the Lambda function for 2nd Intent and the error.

```
def build_response(message):
    return {
        "dialogAction":{
            "type":"Close",
            "fulfillmentState":"Fulfilled",
            "message":{
                "contentType":"PlainText",
                "content":message
            }
        }
    }


def perform_action(intent_request):
    source = intent_request['invocationSource']
    output_session_attributes = intent_request['sessionAttributes'] if intent_request['sessionAttributes'] is not None else {}

    if source == 'FulfillmentCodeHook':
        # action fulfillment code
        build_response('PhotoTakingKIT is triggered and closed...')


def dispatch(intent_request):
    intent_name = intent_request['currentIntent']['name']
    if intent_name == 'PhotoTakingKIT':
        return perform_action(intent_request)
    raise Exception('Intent with name ' + intent_name + ' not supported')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return dispatch(event)
```

[image]

What is the problem, how can i work further with my 2nd Intent.

Comment: modify your code, put log statements, and post detailed log of error, then people can help you faster

Comment: That means to have a detail log about the lambda function i need to add some code in my function.

Comment: yep. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-logging.html  or https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-logging.html